# Dynamically change GStreamer plugin (equalizer) parameters

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer

Context: I have an audio device running Mopidy, which outputs to a gstreamer pipeline. My device has an interface for an equalizer - for this I've set up my ALSA config to go through ALSA equalizer - the GStreamer pipeline targets this. The code that handles the interface uses python `alsamixer` to realise the values.

This works, but ALSA equalizer is a bit janky and has a very narrow range before it distorts the audio. GStreamer has an [equalizer plugin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/equalizer/equalizer-10bands.html?gi-language=c#equalizer-10bands) which I think is better; I can implement this as per the example launch line at:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=song.ogg ! oggdemux ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! equalizer-10bands band2=3.0 ! alsasink
```

However, I want to be able to dynamically change `band0-band9` parameters while the stream is playing - either via python or from the command line. I'm not sure what direction to look - is this possible?

Comment: I use the ladspa `mbeq` so can't say for sure but the object should have `get` and `set` functions. `.get_property("band3")` and `.set_property("band3", 4.33)` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Properties from a plugin can be set via `g_object_set()` function. Whether they can be changed on the fly or only when the pipeline is stopped depends on the plugin's implementation.